# MAC Pycharm - Tkinter button color issue

Tags: python, pycharm

I am currently learning on how to use Tkinter on Pycharm and I am running into an issue where when I asign a color to a button, it doesnt work. The output display is flickering black and white and the designated color is not appearing.

I am using a Mac book Air 2022, macOS Ventura 13.3 and using PyCharm

PyCharm 2023.1 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-231.8109.197, built on March 29, 2023
Licensed to -
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.3
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1024M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.jetbrains.edu (2023.3-2023.1-277)

[Image of the display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rAv5.png)

```
# import modules
from tkinter import *

# create window
window = Tk()
window.title("Python GUI with Tkinter - Frames")

# create widgets
top_frame = Frame(window)
bottom_frame = Frame(window)
top_frame.pack()
bottom_frame.pack()

text1 = Label(top_frame, text="This application demonstrates frame layout")
button1 = Button(bottom_frame, text="Button 1", fg="Red")
button2 = Button(bottom_frame, text="Button 2", fg="Yellow")
button3 = Button(bottom_frame, text="Button 3", fg="Blue")

# place widgets into window container using the pack layout
text1.grid()
button1.grid()
button2.grid()
button3.grid()

# open window
window.mainloop()

I have tried reinstalling PsCharm, updating, changing the code.
I have also reviewed other questions and solutions did not work.
```